# Is nesting supported by lightning-record-edit-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

To save quite a lot of work, it would be great if this is supported:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={record1Id} object-api-name="Type1__c">
    ...
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={record2Id} object-api-name="Type2__c">
        ...
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    ...
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

but on my first attempt the fields of the inner `lightning-record-edit-form` were all blank.

Anyone seen this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's covered in the lightning-record-edit-form documentation for [Usage Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation#:%7E:text=Usage%20Considerations)

> **Nesting lighting-record-edit-form in another instance of the component**, or nesting it in lightning-record-form or lightning-record-view-form **is not supported**.

Comment: Thanks Kris. As ever should have RTFM'd more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was easy enough to move the nested form into its own simple LWC, so that looks like one approach to take for this situation.